# Loading buffer data from database as PDF

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, pdf

I have been developing a web app where the user can upload a PDF file, and then later retrieve it and view it. What I have been doing to achieve this is having the PDF uploaded to a PostgreSQL database as bytea datatype (the column is called "attachment"), and then having nodeJS offer up this data to be fetched back and turned back into a PDF to view.

However I have been struggling to convert the data back into a valid PDF. This is the method I am using so far.

```
var file = new Blob([res[i].attachment], { type: 'application/pdf' });
var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
document.getElementById("pdf_box").data = fileURL;
```

The #pdf_box identifier refers to an object element in a HTML file which is used to display the PDF (this has been shown to work when I provide the file location of a dummy PDF file to the data attribute of this element).

The res[i].attachment is also shown to provide valid buffer data in JSON format, with an example provided below:

```
"attachment":{"type":"Buffer","data":[91,111,98,106,101,99,116,32,70,105,108,101,93]}
```

When I load the created fileURL into the data attribute of #pdf_box however, I get an error indicating along the lines of an invalid PDF file. My research so far appears to indicate this may be because the data is coming in as buffer whereas it needs to be in byte form, but I haven't found much that helps show me how this may be achieved or if there is a way to convert between the forms with the data I have access to? I have also seen occasional reference to a method called pdf.create(), but I cannot find documentation on this and I assume it must belong to a third-party library for JS.

If you know of any information that can help me with understanding what my problem is and what to search to figure out a solution, it would all be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Usually you do not save file contents to database (I can upload 100 x 100Mb files and your DB capacity is greatly reduced). You upload files to some storage place: CDN, AWS S3, save on server, etc. In database you save only URL to resource. In UI part you use some PDF viewer to show element from URL

Comment: To add to this too, using `<object id="pdf" data="../files/test.pdf" type="application/pdf"></object>` seems to be the most effective native way I have found of displaying PDFs in your app without opening the file. To adjust it dynamically you can modify the data attribute as such `document.getElementById("pdf").data = '../files/test2.pdf'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To all reading this question, this method does not seem possible and would likely be incredibly inefficient to implement. If you send a string to nodeJS larger than the MTU of your link to this server (anywhere between 68 bytes and >1500 bytes depending on every component of your network) the packet will be silently dropped with no attempts to resolve or throw an error. What you must do is take the approach of using "multipart/form-data" encoding to send any files to the server (more on this found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63213895/post-cutting-off-pdf-data)).

It should also be mentioned that uploading a file to the database is not recommended in any capacity (due to databases being quite inefficient storage for large amounts of data) and what should be done is to upload a reference to the file path or URL to find the file at. Then on the client-side this file could be rendered as such when you have retrieved the file location...

```
<object id="pdf" data="../files/test.pdf"></object>
```

To change the data attribute, the following can be done...

```
document.getElementById("pdf").data = "../files/test2.pdf";
```