# POST cutting off PDF data

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, pdf

I posted a question yesterday (linked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63205715/loading-buffer-data-from-database-as-pdf)) where I had been trying to send a PDF to a database, and then retrieve it a later date. Since then I have been advised that it is best to (in my case as I cannot use Cloud Computing services) to upload the PDF files to local storage, and save the URL of the file to the database instead. I have now begun implementing this, but I have come across some trouble.

I am currently using FileReader() as documented below to process the input file and send it to the server:

```
var input_file = "";
let reader = new FileReader();
reader.readAsText(document.getElementById("input_attachment").files[0]);
reader.onloadend = function () {
    input_file = "&file=" + reader.result;
    const body = /*all the rest of my data*/ + input_file;
    const method = {
        method: "POST",
        body: body,
        headers: {
            "Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        }
    };
```

After this bloc of code I do the stock standard fetch() and a route on my server receives this. Almost all data comes in 100% as expected, but the file comes in cut off somewhere around 1300 characters in (making it quite an incomplete PDF). What does appear to come in seems to match the first 1300 characters of the original PDF I uploaded.

I have seen suggestions that you are meant to use "multipart/form-data" content-type to upload files, but when I do this I seem to only then receive the first 700 characters or so of my PDF. I have tried using the middleware Multer to handle the "multipart/form-data" but it just doesn't seem to upload anything (though I can't guarantee that I am using it correctly).

I also initially had trouble with **fetch payload too large** error message, but have currently resolved this through this method:

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ limit: "50mb", extended: false, parameterLimit: 50000 }));
```

Though I have suspicions that this may not be correctly implemented as I have seen some discussion that the urlencoded limit is set prior to the file loading, and cannot be changed in the middle of the program.

Any and all help is greatly appreciated, and I will likely use any information here to construct an answer on my original question from yesterday so that anybody else facing these sort of issues have a resource to go to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I personally found the solution to this problem as follows. On the client-side of my application this code is an example of what was implemented.

```
formData = new FormData();
formData.append("username", "John Smith");
formData.append("fileToUpload", document.getElementById("input_attachment").files[0]);
const method = {
    method: "POST",
    body: formData
};
fetch(url, method)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(res => alert("File uploaded!"))
    .catch(err => alert(err.message))
```

As can be noted I have changed from using "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" encoding to "multipart/form-data" to upload files. nodeJS and Express however do not natively support this encoding type. I chose to use the library Formidable (found this to be easiest to use without too much overhead) which can be investigated about [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/formidable). Below is an example of my server-side implementation of this middleware (Formidable).

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const formidable = require('formidable');

app.post('/upload', (req, res) => {
    const form = formidable({ uploadDir: `${__dirname}/file/`, keepExtensions: true });
    form.parse(req, (err, fields, files) => {
        if (err) console.log(err.stack);
        else {
            console.log(fields.username);
    });
});
```

The file(s) are automatically uploaded to the directory specified in uploadDir, and the keepExtensions ensures that the file extension is saved as well. The non-file inputs are accessible through the fields object as seen through the fields.username example above.

From what I have found, this is the easiest method to take to setup an easy file upload system.